# LXD container ALSA audio support question

Tags: ubuntu, audio, ubuntu-18.04, lxd

host: Ubuntu 18.04
LXD/LXC 3.0.3

I am trying to use ALSA in my ubuntu 18.04 container. 
ALSA on host works.
I have seen [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/844437/error-in-playing-a-sound-using-alsa-inside-lxc-container) but it doesn't work for me.

My configuration:

```
lxc config set mycontainer raw.lxc "lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 116:* rwm"
lxc config set mycontainer raw.lxc "lxc.mount.entry = /dev/snd dev/snd none bind,optional,create=dir 0 0"
```

aplay: aplay -l aplay: device_list:270: no soundcards found..

ALSA on the host works perfectly well.

What else do I need to do to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, I have managed to get it working.
Found this [post](https://discuss.linuxcontainers.org/t/pcie-sound-card-passthrough/2716)

```
lxc config device add <container> pcmC0D2c unix-char path=/dev/snd/pcmC0D2c
```

I have added all devices listed in`/dev/snd`:

```
hwC0D0 hwC0D2 pcmC0D0c pcmC0D0p pcmC0D10p pcmC0D1p pcmC0D2c pcmC0D3p pcmC0D7p pcmC0D8p pcmC0D9p seq timer
```

It is important to add `seq` and `timer`, as well.